# feature selection using perceptron

Tags: matlab

Do you know an example that makes feature selection using a perceptron, maybe an implementation on matlab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is a binary linear classifier, that is, it can classify n-dimensional data that look like this:

[image]

but not like this:

[image]

into two distinct categories. Just like any other neural network, it first needs to be trained on a training set, and then only it can be used to classify new data points.

The perceptron can therefore be applied to classify any linearly separable dataset. A Matlab implementation is available in the Neural Network toolbox (see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/perceptron.html)). An excellent toolbox for pattern recognition in general, with excellent classifiers, is PRTools, which is kind of the open source variant of the commercial toolbox [PRSD Studio](http://prsdstudio.com/).